# Keep asking user to input data, stuck in endless loop

Tags: java, while-loop, user-input

I want my user to keep inputting employee numbers until the user inputs -1, which stops the loop. But my code keeps printing the inputted numbers and won't ask another question.

```
    System.out.println("Which employee number do you want to see -->");
    index = myScanner.nextInt();

    while (payData.getOneEmpNum(index) != -1)
    {
        if (payData.getOneEmpNum(index) >= 0)
        {   
            System.out.printf("Sequential found employee #%d ",payData.getOneEmpNum(index));
            System.out.printf("and the pay rate is $%.2f.\n ",  payData.getPayRate(index));

            System.out.printf("Binary found employee #%d ",payData.getOneEmpNum(index));
            System.out.printf("and the pay rate is $%.2f.\n ",  payData.getPayRate(index));
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid employee number!");
        }

        System.out.println("Which employee number do you want to see -->");
    }
```

Comment: I don't see where you ask for input inside the `while()` loop?  What would cause `payData.getOneEmpNum(index)` to change, causing the loop to break?

Comment: get the next input inside the loop

**index = myScanner.nextInt();**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not updating `index` within your while loop. Add this line at the end of your loop:

```
index = myScanner.nextInt();
```

after `System.out.println("Which employee number do you want to see -->");`

Comment: Thanks but now it won't print the line if its an invalid number. It just ends the loop

Comment: Isn't that the whole point ... to end the loop when the user provides -1?

Comment: Yes but it also needs to be valid in my if statement. I also tried while (payData.getOneEmpNum(index) != -1 || payData.getOneEmpNum(index) >= 0) and it still passes though the loop if i input 200. It should say invalid number and ask the question again

Comment: Of course it passes through! You are TELLING the program to accept a number if it's >= 0. Please use a debugger for things like this, otherwise this exchange of comments will turn into a full-blown conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you updated your code, looks like you just need a `index = myScanner.nextInt();` inside of your while loop.  The way you have it set up currently, you'll want it underneath the last `println` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace first few lines of your code :

```
while ((index = myScanner.nextInt()) != -1)
{
    if (payData.getOneEmpNum(index) >= 0)
    {
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  In Java, `x = y` will return a `boolean` based on success, not an `integer` of the result of the operation?  Maybe I'm wrong though.

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, not comparative operator. `x == y` will return boolean value which I have not used here. @mash

Comment: yes, the assignment operator _returns_ a value.  I believe it returns a `boolean` indicating success (that's what c++ does)

Comment: `myScanner.nextInt()` will never return boolean value, it will return `integer` -> that integer will by assigned to `index` by `=` operator -> now this value (value of index) will be compared with `-1` for inequality with `!=` operator. C, C++, C# or Java, In any language, this is what will happen. I don't understand what is not clear here. @mash. It is better to try above answer before asking doubt.

Comment: I was actually incorrect saying C++ returns a boolean on success here, it does actually return the object assigned, as does Java.  So yes this would work, sorry!